# Change the php.ini file MAMP Pro uses?

Tags: mamp-pro

Can I change the `php.ini` file MAMP Pro uses?

By default, MAMP Pro uses this php.ini:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path   /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.2/conf
```

Is there a way to use:

```
Configuration File (php.ini) Path: /usr/local/etc/php/7.4
```

This is my system `php.ini` file, running `php -i` I can see *ImageMagick supported formats* shows `WebP` is supported.

My hope is if I can configure MAMP Pro to use this Configuration File (php.ini) Path: `/usr/local/etc/php/7.4` instead of the default one I'd be able generate WebP images via my Content Management System (CMS)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Try copying /usr/local/etc/php/7.4 to /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.4.1 (or some unique version) and then Stop server, shut down MAMP, restart it Start server.

Now you should have the ability to access the php.ini file in MAMP: File, Edit Template, PHP, PHP 7.4.1.